# Why do I get quadratic time sorting using STL sort()?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, quadratic

I was trying to sort a vector of objects by values stored in a map, using the STL sort() function. To my great surprise, my algorithm was running in quadratic time. I simplified it as much as I could, trying to pinpoint an apparent bug, but to no avail. Here is the simplified version:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct a{
  map<a*,float> vals;
  bool operator()(a* a1, a* a2){return (vals[a1]>vals[a2]);}
  void asort();
};

void a::asort(){
  vector<a*> v;
  map<a*,float>::iterator it = vals.begin();
  for(;it!=vals.end();it++){v.push_back((*it).first);}
  sort(v.begin(),v.end(),*this);
}

int main(){
  a a0;
  int imax=8000;
  for(int i=0;i<imax;i++){a0.vals[new a]=rand();}
  a0.asort();
}
```

When I run it for imax=2000, 4000, 8000, it takes about 1s, 4s, 18s respectively. How is this possible? Why don't I get the expected imax*log(imax) dependence? I have limited experience with C++, please help! Thanks!

**Update:** thank you Xeo, Rick and everyone who responded. As Xeo and Rick explained, the problem is that the comparator (in my case `struct a` with the map containing values) gets copied on each comparison, hence the computational complexity `O(imax^2 log(imax))`. One way around this that I can see (so that changes to my code are minimal) is to use a pointer to the map, namely `map<a*,float>* vals`, instead of `map<a*,float> vals`. Then the map copying is avoided, and the complexity is back to `O(imax log(imax))`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure the time is consumed by sort instead of other calculations?

Comment: do you really need to call sort on a map (its already ordered)

Comment: @FamZheng: there are no other calculations, the times are for the code you see

Comment: @Rick: The code is not sorting the map, but a vector of pointers based on the floats those pointers map to.

Comment: @Rick: I need to sort by values of the map. How is it already sorted? I do not understand. Do you mean I can have my vector v without resorting to sort()?

Comment: yep. I read the code more closely, the map is being copied each time compare is called. implement a functor or stand alone compare should fix.

Comment: @Rick: Not every time the comparator is called, only once when `asort` is called.

Comment: thats not what my debugger & profiler are telling me.

Comment: @Rick: Right, I forgot the implementation is allowed to copy the predicate as often as it likes, which it most likely will with `_impl` functions.

Comment: It would help if you looked up the implementation of your std::sort function (or just tell us what the version so we can look it up).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) takes its predicate *by value*, meaning

```
sort(v.begin(),v.end(),*this);
//                     ^^^^^
```

will copy the contained map.

Next, you're doing a map lookup twice during the comparision, which is `O(log N)`, while it's expected that `pred(a,b)` is a constant operation.

You can fix this by defining a seperate comparator for `std::sort` and using `std::unordered_map` (C++11).

Comment: @Mark: Inside `a::operator()`, you get map lookup when mapping from `a*` to `float`. And how would `O(n)` favour the longer input? `vals.size() == n` in the OP's code, meaning longer time to copy and do the lookup.

Comment: Do you mean that I get an extra factor of N from copying the map? Why would it create a copy of the map on each comparison? Sorry, I am confused why I am getting ~ O(N^2)

Comment: @Flash: Take a look at the `std::sort` link in my answer. The third parameter is `Compar comp`, which will make a copy of whatever you pass as the third argument. In this case, that is `*this`, which contains a map whose size is equal to `imax`, and as such cause an `O(imax)` copy. :)

Comment: I agree that the third argument is copied at least once. But O(imax^2), if I understand correctly, can only arise from spending extra factor of O(imax) on each comparison. Why then the map is copied every time?

Comment: @FlashCards: Remember that you're doing the map lookup inside of `operator()`, which adds `O(log imax)`. Also, your function isn't completely quadratic it seems.

Comment: But the map look up should be O(log N), correct? Where O(N) is coming from? Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: @Flash: You're not missing anything, there is no `O(imax)` in *every* loop iteration, only `O(2*log imax)` which is `O(log imax)`, but then again, the execution time doesn't really seem quadratic. A question, though, are you compiling in release mode with optimizations on?

Comment: the function looks approximately quadratic to me, up to a factor of log(imax) which I ignore. One can run the code to see this. Maybe I have some issues with my compiler?

Comment: sorry, why is it not quadratic? For every doubling of imax, the runtime (roughly) quadruples. I call it (roughly) quadratic.

Comment: @Flash: Really, no idea where else the slowdown could hide. But then again, did you compile in release mode with optimizations enabled?

Comment: I compiled: g++ code.cpp, g++ -O code.cpp, g++ -O2 code.cpp. It remains quadratic, only a constant pre-factor changes.

Comment: @Flash: New idea: `std::sort` is allowed to copy the predicate as it sees fit and can and will most likely pass it to some internal implementation function, which might very well happen on every iteration. There you get your `O(n)` copy.

Answer (score 1):

A map is already sorted. `std::sort` is probably based on Quicksort, whose worst-case performance is when the input is pre-sorted.

Comment: The vector is sorted based on the floats the `a*` map to. Also, [`std::sort` has a specified complexity of `O(N log N)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), and is typically implemented with *introsort*, an algorithm that adapts depending on the input.

Comment: std::sort is more complex, its a combination insertion sort / quicksort IIRC (you can just look). But you'd think there would be an overload for map that simply returned...

Comment: @Rick, it will depend on the specific implementation. The question didn't mention a compiler.

Comment: no it didn't, but you can just look in your distribution which was my point (sorry for not being clear).

Comment: @Xeo, is that specification for average or worst case?

Comment: @MarkRandom Worst case would be O(N^2), however, I'd be very surprised if the standard library wasn't using a quicksort with randomized pivot choice.

Comment: @Yuushi: They're not. As I said in my first comment, all libraries I know use an algorithm called introsort.